# How can I search by slug using GraphQL? - "Unknown argument \"slug\" on field \"article\"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, slug, strapi

I'm fiddling around in GraphQL playground trying to build a query to retrieve an article based on its slug. My backend is running on Strapi and I've constructed a 'Article' type with a text field named 'slug'. I could access this by id (and this appears to work) but I'd prefer to access it by slug so I can build pages with human-friendly urls.

I have a dummy article with id of 9 and slug of "a".

My query looks like this:

```
query Articles {
    article (  slug: "a"  ) {
        title
    }
}
```

Upon doing this I recieve an error:

```
"message": "Unknown argument \"slug\" on field \"article\" of type \"Query\".",
```

This is confusing to me since the docs [here](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/) indicate that I should be able to pass fields as arguments and search accordingly, but even if I interchange slug with title or author I recieve a similar error. The only thing I can reliably search by is ID:

```
query Articles {
    article (  id: "9"  ) {
        title
    }
}
```

This correctly retrieves the targeted article's information. Where am I going wrong here? I've tried all sorts now.

[See my query / response here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoDlv.png). Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the `find` (aka the plural form, as the singular uses the `findOne`) you have to use a where filter:

```
query Articles {
    article (where: { slug: "a" }) {
        title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strapi is working differently than the solution from above. What worked for me was:

```
query Articles ($slug: String!) {
articles(filters: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
....}
```

You have to follow this for querying:

> filters: { field: { operator: value } }

More info in the documentation about filters, [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/graphql-api.html#filters)

Comment: how to get only one article,

Comment: @Travis To get one article, you have to filter by id or some attribute like a slug here which is also possible since a slug should be unique.

Comment: Exact as pensum says @Travis. You can use the same example from above but remember to pass $slug as a variable.